# struct pointer to another struct

Tags: c, struct

I have those 2 structures and that simple init function.

```
typedef struct ls{
    int k;
    struct ls *next;
} NOD;

typedef struct h{
    int k;
    NOD *lis;
    struct h *next;
} hash;
```

My init function looks like this:

```
hash *init_h(hash *h){
    h=NULL;
    h->lis=NULL;
    return h;
}
```

In main:

```
hash *h;
h=init_h(h);
```

When I run the program it crashes instantly.
I use CodeBlocks. Could it be the problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: ~150 lines. but that is the essential. those structs and the call for init_h.

Comment: `h` is `NULL`... `h->list` will crash the program immediately. You have to `malloc` a piece of memory first, or simply `return calloc(1, sizeof(hash));`

Comment: You first set `h` to `NULL`, and then you try to dereference it.  Of **course** you're going to get a runtime error.  You cannot dereference a `NULL` pointer.  Why do you even have it as a parameter if the first thing you do is locally override the value?  It makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks ! Now i get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash *init_h(hash *h){
    h=NULL;       // h is set to NULL
    h->lis=NULL;  // then you dereference NULL.... crash
    return h;
}
```

You can't dereference a NULL pointer

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought that if you assign NULL to a pointer of pointer it crashes...

Comment: @ZuzUBA It's not the 1st line, it's the second. You tell the machine go find the value at addressed NULL and get me the value that would be positioned at 'lis'.  NULL is in invalid address to deref.

Comment: @ZuzUBA You have to understand why it happens. Your memory space is divided into sections, which some can be read and some can be written. The memory at 0x0 cannot be read or written, so the kernel sends a segfault signal and terminates the program.

Comment: I like the undefined function call `new` :-). You should just do the `malloc` statement to make it more transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not allocate memory for `h*`.

```
h=NULL;
h->lis=NULL; // NULL pointer dereference = undefined behavior = crash
```

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 it is undefined and is different depending on architecture, for example in real mode IVT is located there and one may actually want to write/read something into it